# Django - limit_choices_to users within a group model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a group models with members and one admin which looks like this:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='members')
    is_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, limit_choices_to={'members': True})
```

**I want to show only members which are part of the group to the is_admin field.**

I tried the limit_choices_to method and referred the members but it is not working when I try to display the users in a form like this: `form = EditGroupForm(instance=group)`. How can I do so?